# In my laravel application, validation errors are not getting displayed in the view. How can i achieve it?

Tags: laravel, validation, view

I am using Laravel Framework 5.8.15. I am validating some of my form inputs. After the failure of validator, it redirects me back to the view but does not display any of the errors.

My controller is :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'donator_first_name' => 'required|alpha|max:50',
            'donator_middle_name' => 'required|alpha|max:50',
            ]);

            donations::create([
              'donator_first_name' => $request->get('donator_first_name'),
              'donator_middle_name'=> $request->get('donator_middle_name')
            ]);

            return back()->with('success', 'You have just created one item');
    }
```

My form is:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Donator's Surname: </label>
                <input class="form-control"  id="donator_last_name" name="donator_last_name"  placeholder="Enter Surname" required>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Donator's First Name: </label>
                <input class="form-control" id="donator_first_name" name="donator_first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Donator's Father's Name: </label>
                <input class="form-control" id="donator_middle_name" name="donator_middle_name" value="{{ old('donator_middle_name') }}" placeholder="Enter Father's Name" required>
            </div>
```

My view is:

```
@if ($errors->any())
            {{dd($errors)}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
          @endif

          @if (\Session::get('success'))
              <div class="alert alert-success">
                  <p>{{ \Session::get('success') }}</p>
              </div>
          @endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

evrything seems to be fine with your code. dont forget to add {{ csrf_field() }} to the form.

on the view try this:

```
 @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <strong>Error!</strong> 
                                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                            <p>{{ $error }}</p>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </div>
                                        @endif

                                        @if(session('success'))
                                        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                            <strong>Successfull!</strong> 
                                            {{ session('success') }}
                                        </div>                        
                                       @endif

                                        @if(session('wrong'))
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                            <strong>Error!</strong> 
                                            {{ session('wrong') }}
                                        </div>                        
                                       @endif
```

then your controller try this:

```
return redirect("urlpath")->with('success','You have just created one item');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it it is displaying empty in the view. @samju

Comment: I can not find the reason why it is not showing me the session data. If i print the session in the controller it displays but it does not display the same in the view.

Comment: try this on your controller 'use Session;'

Comment: yes it shows the alert (because i had removed the if condition)  but empty. Does not show any message

Answer (score 0):

I was calling an API in the form submit action . And That is why i was not able to get the sessions in my view.